# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK"

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podfile, fastlane-gym

I'm using Fastlane with unity plugin and gym. After unity step I have a Podfile with pods:

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'AppLovinMediationGoogleAdapter', '10.6.0.0'
  pod 'AppLovinMediationUnityAdsAdapter', '4.7.1.0'
  pod 'AppLovinSDK', '11.10.1'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 14.1'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit_Basics', '~> 14.1'
  pod 'FBSDKGamingServicesKit', '~> 14.1'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 14.1'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 14.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '10.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '10.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '10.11.0'
  pod 'Protobuf'
  pod 'UnityMediationAdmobAdapter', :source => 'https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/unity-mediation-cocoapods-prod.git'
  pod 'UnityMediationSdk', '~> 1.0', :source => 'https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/unity-mediation-cocoapods-prod.git'
  pod 'UnityMediationUnityAdapter', :source => 'https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/unity-mediation-cocoapods-prod.git'
end
target 'Unity-iPhone' do
end
```

But when I try to build, cocoapods step crashes

```
    cocoapods(
      clean_install: true,
      repo_update: true
    )
```

With Error

```
-----------------------
--- Step: cocoapods ---
-----------------------
$ bundle exec pod install --clean-install --repo-update
▸ Updating local specs repositories
▸ Analyzing dependencies
▸ [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK":
▸ In Podfile:
▸ AppLovinMediationGoogleAdapter (= 10.6.0.0) was resolved to 10.6.0.0, which depends on
▸ Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (= 10.6.0)
▸ UnityMediationAdmobAdapter was resolved to 0.5.0, which depends on
▸ Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 8.2)
Exit status of command 'bundle exec pod install --clean-install --repo-update' was 1 instead of 0.
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK":
  In Podfile:
    AppLovinMediationGoogleAdapter (= 10.6.0.0) was resolved to 10.6.0.0, which depends on
      Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (= 10.6.0)
    UnityMediationAdmobAdapter was resolved to 0.5.0, which depends on
      Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 8.2)
```

I tried using different versions of `AppLovinMediationGoogleAdapter` and `UnityMediationAdmobAdapter` but it didn't work

Comment: It looks like you have a dependency conflict between 2 different packages. If you check the .podspec file from that [link](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/unity-mediation-cocoapods-prod/blob/master/UnityMediationAdmobAdapter/1.0.0/UnityMediationAdmobAdapter.podspec), you can see its dependencies so if you manipulate the file, you can find a common dependency for the different 2 packages in conflict.